# MCU: Significance to the designation of Earth-199999

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel

There is evidence that the past Marvel editors and writers used easter eggs or dating conventions in the naming of different Marvel Universes.

For example:

- The *Marvel Zombies vs Army of Darkness* universe exists as Earth-818793, paying homage to the release years of the Evil Dead trilogy (1981, 1987, 1993).
- From the *What If?* series, many of those universes were officially derived from their publication date (Earth-929 from Sept-92, etc).

**Question**: Is there significance to the name Earth-199999, or is it just a random number?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question over on M&TV, [and has an answer there](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17171/what-is-the-significance-behind-the-mcus-numerical-designation)

Comment: Coincidentally, I just noticed that too. I'm thinking the answer is that it's just a random number, which is okay, I guess, but kinda...boring. No numerology, birth dates etc, just someone holding the 9 key a little bit too long, probably. :(

Comment: I suppose it's worth wondering what significance the number 200000 has. If 199999 has any significance, there's a decent chance it's tied to that. A google search for "200000" returns a lot of links referencing the first modern humans appearing about 200,000 years ago, but I don't know why that would be relevant. Still, 199999 is such a specific number that if there is an "Earth-200000" or something similar, it could be related.  Or it could just be random.

Comment: There are a LOT of marvel universes: http://marvel.wikia.com/Multiverse/Universe_Listing

Comment: Maybe there are 199,998 universes’ worth of other comics just sitting in Marvel’s vaults, waiting to be released.

Comment: According to [Marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-199999): *This universe's official designation was revealed in Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z Volume 5 hardcover.*

Comment: i'm sure I read somewhere that it referred to a meeting in 1999 when they started planning the MCU, but I can't find any reference for it

Answer (score 0):

I think it is supposed be really far away and separated from the other universes because in this one, the X-Men, Fantastic Four, and Spiderman (until now) didn't exist. It is very different from Earth-616.

Comment: Although I suspect you're right, this answer seems to be based more on supposition than actual evidence.

Comment: this would make sense except that the universe numbers go *way* past 199999 and there's a bunch of them right in the 200000's