# Earth-616 vs Earth-1218

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I've just found out about Earth-616 and Earth-1218. What is the main difference between the two and which "Earth" is the one we see in the current Marvel movies?

**EDIT**

Just found out Earth-199999 is the Cinematic Marvel Universe... but why? where do these numbers originate from?

Comment: Are you looking for how the creators come up with the numbers or their significance, if any, to the continuity?

Comment: asking about the significance of the number 199999 has already been asked [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54497/5184), but we've never gotten any sufficient answers. there's more related discussion [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49641/5184) and [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59922/5184)

Comment: See also [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/what-is-the-difference-between-marvels-ultimate-universe-earth-1610-and-the-c) for discussion of character mapping as influenced by movie rights... Newer than that answer, though, it appears [Spider-Man will segue into MCU](http://marvel.com/news/movies/24062/sony_pictures_entertainment_brings_marvel_studios_into_the_amazing_world_of_spider-man).

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what Wikipedia has on the history of the term "616-Universe".

> The term was first used in "Rough Justice," a story credited to both
>   Alan Moore and Alan Davis published in July 1983 by Marvel UK in the
>   anthology comic The Daredevils (and was later reprinted in the Captain
>   Britain trade paperback). Saturnyne uses the term to differentiate
>   Brian Braddock, the Captain Britain of the regular Marvel Comics
>   universe, from the other members of the Captain Britain Corps, each of
>   which inhabit different universes. The designation was later used by
>   the American branch of Marvel Comics in the Excalibur title, which
>   frequently referenced Captain Britain's early UK-published adventures.
>   This comic was written by Chris Claremont, who had created Captain
>   Britain, and by Alan Davis, the artist on the UK-published series.
>
> Alan Moore is usually credited with creating the term. However, Alan
>   Davis has stated that the designation of Earth 616 was actually first
>   made by Dave Thorpe, the previous writer of the UK-published Captain
>   Britain stories.
>
> In addition, a difference of opinion exists regarding the selection of
>   the number 616. In 2005, Alan Moore's son-in-law John Reppion (who is
>   married to Alan Moore's daughter Leah Moore), stated on an Internet
>   message board that the number 616 was arbitrarily chosen by Moore and
>   had no significant meaning, saying it "was just a random number of no
>   significance chosen because people always seemed to be talking about
>   'earth 2' or 'earth 4' but never any higher numbers."
>   However, Alan Davis has said that it comes from 616, a variation on
>   the Number of the Beast, picked because Dave Thorpe "wasn't a fan of
>   the modern superhero genre" and expressed this in his stories, "such
>   as recording his opinion of the Marvel Universe with the designation
>   616.